# How to access DOM attributes containing different attribute values using Cheerio?

Tags: jquery-selectors, cheerio

I'm using `cheerio` to scrape the webpage in `nodejs`. Now I've come across content of the web which is structured something like this,

```
<div data-content="123456"> ... </div>
<div data-content="142453"> ... </div>
<div data-content="192638"> ... </div>
<div data-content="152701"> ... </div>
<div data-content="172830"> ... </div>
```

note that `data-content` attribute has different attribute values and within the div there is necessary data that i want to scrape out. How can i use cheerio to access the DOM attributes that are structured like this?

NOTE : I know using `div` as a selector is possible. But i don't want to use `div` as a selector with cheerio. i want to exclusively use `data-content` as a selector to access DOM nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('div[data-content]')
```